# How to get .msi from powershell?

Tags: powershell, msbuild, continuous-integration, nuget, devenv

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script for Bamboo that will:

- Build the installer to create an msi
- Find all Unit Test projects (any .csproj files that end in 'UnitTests') and compile them.

After a bit of searching, I found that I can call `$env:RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets='false'` to finally get NuGet packages restored, and now things are building... except the installer msi. It gives this output:

> ```
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.8.2.
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. All rights reserved.
>
> The license for Visual Studio expires in 29 days.
>
> Some errors occurred during migration. For more information, see the migration report:
> C:\Program Files\Atlassian\Application Data\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\CD-VX10-JOB1\UpgradeLog.htm
> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Core, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
> 2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Repositories, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
> 3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Services, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
> 4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: VX10Desktop, Configuration: Release x86 ------
> ========== Rebuild All: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

Looking at the log as advised, it shows the following error:

> Installer\Installer.vdproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=660952&projecttype=54435603-DBB4-11D2-8724-00A0C9A8B90C

Here's my script:

```
#Constants:
$devEnv = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv"

#External Variables:
$nuget = $env:nuget

function Main {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
    $sln = Get-SolutionFile
    
    Restore-NugetPackages $sln
    Compile-DesktopProject $sln

    exit $LASTEXITCODE
}

function Compile-DesktopProject($slnFile) {
    $projectFile = Get-ChildItem "*.vdproj" -Recurse
    $filePath = $projectFile.FullName
    Run-Cmd("& `'$devEnv' /Rebuild Release '$slnFile'")#Build everything but vdproj
    Run-Cmd("& `'$devEnv' /Rebuild Release '$slnFile' /Project '$filePath'")#Build vdproj - NOT WORKING
}

function Get-SolutionFile {
    $files = ls *.sln
    if($files.Count -ne 1){
        echo 'Expected exactly one .sln file.'
        exit 1 
    }
    $file = $files[0]
    return $file
}

function Restore-NugetPackages($slnFile) {
    $env:RestoreUseSkipNonexistentTargets='false'
    Run-Cmd("& `'$($nuget)' restore '$($slnFile)'")
}

function Run-Cmd($cmd){
    write-host "Running: $cmd"
    Invoke-Expression $cmd
}

Main
```

Why is my .msi not building and how can I make this work?

---

Worth noting: When, on my local machine, I restore NuGet packages in Visual Studio and then run my DevEnv, it works and the msi is created.
It's only when I run the PowerShell script on the Bamboo server that that the msi isn't created.
So maybe it has something to do with the server/DevEnv installation?

Comment: `*.vdproj` projects can only be compiled by `devenv` command line.

Comment: @LexLi I am aware of this. But it's failing because there are no NuGet packages.